# Creating POJOs for json with single field containing Array with RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I am creating a client for the following format of JSON -

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "Product": "K265113",
            "Language": "EN",
            "LongText": "FIXTURE,INTERIOR,WALL"
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON always contains "results" field which is an array of a single element (it will always be a single element in this array). I just need LongText field from the JSON and nothing else. I am using Spring RESTTemplate.

I know that it works if I create two DTOs like -

```
public class ParentDTO
{
    private List<ChildDTO> results;

    public List<ChildDTO> getResults()
    {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<ChildDTO> results)
    {
        this.results = results;
    }
}


public class ChildDTO
{
    private String longText;

    public String getLongText()
    {
        return longText;
    }

    @JsonProperty("LongText")
    public void setLongText(String longText)
    {
        this.longText = longText;
    }
}
```

But is there any way to read longText by creating a single DTO as the parent DTO is not having any useful field as I know there will always but just one element in the results array.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you need only single DTO could be that you want only single class to perform this task. You can achieve that using ChildDTO as inner class which will make it more readable and maintainable.

The other way is to not parse the spring template response into DTOs instead use **JSONNode** class of Jackson databind API.

```
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(response.getBody());
```

You can find more information at
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html

You can traverse down the tree and could retrieve the value of the attribute directly without any DTOs.